# Need to summarize nodes where data can be empty

Tags: xslt

I have the following XML:

I want to sum all the values in Quantity, altough some of them might miss values completely. How can I do this. Everything I try result in NaN

/M

```
<Top>
 <Lines>
   <Line ID="1" Quantity="1,00" />
   <Line ID="2" Quantity="11,00" />
   <Line ID="3" Quantity="" />
   <Line ID="4" Quantity="" />
   <Line ID="5" Quantity="10,00" />
 </Lines>
</Top>
```

Comment: The problem is not only the empty values, but also the comma as decimal separator. You need to replace it with a period so that the value is considered a number in XML. Can you use a processor that supports XSLT 2.0?

Comment: Yes, it supports XSLT 2.0. Problems with the comma as decimal separator is that the XML is provided by another source, hence I cannot change to persiod. Needs to be done in XSLT in that case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, you have two problems here:

- empty values;
- values containing comma as decimal separator.

In XSLT 2.0 you can solve both problems using the following expression:

```
sum(/Top/Lines/Line[string(@Quantity)]/number(translate(@Quantity, ',', '.')))
```

---

The `[string(@Quantity)]` predicate excludes `Line`s with an empty `Quantity`attribute, and the `number(translate(@Quantity, ',', '.'))` expression converts the others to valid numbers.

Comment: This worked like a charm. Thanks alot for your help!