# Summarize nodes where data can be empty, and if so, set default value

Tags: xslt

Consider this XML

I want to sum all the values in Quantity and for those lines missing a value, I want to use default value of 1,00

I previously asked a question skipping the lines without Quantity
([Need to summarize nodes where data can be empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54665183/need-to-summarize-nodes-where-data-can-be-empty)).

Got a great answer to use

```
sum(/Top/Lines/Line[string(@Quantity)]/number(translate(@Quantity, ',', '.')))
```

How can I adjust the code above to fit my new requirements?

Thanks

/M

```
<Top>
 <Lines>
   <Line ID="1" Quantity="1,00" />
   <Line ID="2" Quantity="11,00" />
   <Line ID="3" Quantity="" />
   <Line ID="4" Quantity="" />
   <Line ID="5" Quantity="10,00" />
 </Lines>
</Top>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're still using XPath/XSLT 2.0, you could so:

```
sum(/Top/Lines/Line/(if (string(@Quantity)) then number(translate(@Quantity, ',', '.')) else 1))
```